# ClassNotFoundException after importing CN1 project from VCS

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to import a Codename One project from my private Bitbucket repo to a second workstation. Both of my workstations run on Windows and are using Java 8. I use IntelliJ IDEA and have checked that all my files have been pushed to my repo.

Strangely, the server can create both Android and iOS builds, but I am unable to run my simulator, which would greatly speed up development. This is the error I get when trying to run the Simulator:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=49613:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:/Users/mypc/IdeaProjects/myApp\out\production\myApp;C:/Users/mypc/IdeaProjects/myApp\src;C:/Users/mypc/IdeaProjects/myApp\lib\CodenameOne.jar;C:/Users/mypc/IdeaProjects/myApp\JavaSE.jar;native/internal_tmp;lib/impl/cls com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator org.myapp.app.Main
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myapp.app.Main
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1004)
            at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
            at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
            at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:86)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

---

However, my `Main` is in the project.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you parsing class names anywhere, i.e. Class.forName() or is this the framework specifically?

Comment: I don't parse class names.

Comment: Is the class `org.myapp.app.Main` located under `C:/Users/mypc/IdeaProjects/myApp\out\production\myApp` ? If you run that command from command line does it work?

Comment: Yes, Main is under that directory. No, I can't get the simulator to run from command line with that command.

Comment: @Shai I tried the command from [this CN1 google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/KWpBdwj8RuI/oH786HNqkuoJ) but I get this error: `Could not find or load main class org.myapp.app.Main`. Is it possible that is a problem because my project name is 2 words with a space -- Main App? My Main class is only 1 word though.... Thanks.

Comment: @Shai, I may have found another clue to fix this: when I right-click on the java files in the `src` folder, the menu does not provide the option to run the app through the simulator/debugger or build a module, etc. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

My repository name was different than my project name, as defined on my primary workspace. When the project was downloaded to my other machine, the repo name was used as the project name. Changing the project name by clicking `File` -> `Project Structure` and then changing the project name back to its real name fixed the problem. Now the simulator works.

Thanks to @Shai Almog for his directions and for giving me this idea.

Answer (score 0):

The directory listed above is: `C:\Users\mypc\IdeaProjects\myApp`.

Is that path correct?

Assuming it is open CMD and do the following:

```
cd C:\Users\mypc\IdeaProjects\myApp
dir
```

In that listing you should see several files. Two important files are: `JavaSE.jar` & `CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar`. I'm assuming both are there as you can send a build.

Next do this:

```
dir out\production\myApp
```

This is where idea should store your application classes when it compiles. I have a sense that this will be missing and it's the reason for this failure. Assuming that's the case look in the `.idea` directory for references to this path and verify that they are correct.

Comment: I ran `dir out\production\myApp` as you suggested and got a `File not found` response so I checked the `.dea` file as you suggested. Everything looked fine.